# Parent variadic function template specialized in child

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

is this code formally ok? Because I not sure if I may specialized template function in child class as in this example:

main.cpp:

```
class Consumer
{
public:
    Consumer() = default;
    ~Consumer() = default;
    template<typename... T>
    void echo(iConnector& connector, T... args)
    {
        connector.transfer(args...);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Consumer c;
    intConnector i;
    stringConnector s;
    c.echo(i, 1);
    c.echo(i, std::string("aaa"));
    c.echo(s, std::string("aaa"));
    c.echo(s, 1);
    return 0;
 }
```

iConnector.h

```
class iConnector {
public:
    iConnector() = default;
    virtual ~iConnector() = default;
    template<typename... T>
    void transfer(T... args) { std::cout << "Not defined\n"; }
};
```

intConnector.h

```
class intConnector : public iConnector {
public:
    intConnector() = default;
    virtual ~intConnector() = default;
};
```

intConnector.cpp

```
template<>
void iConnector::transfer<int>(int i)
{
    std::cout << "intConnector " << i << "\n";
}
```

stringConnector.h

```
class stringConnector : public iConnector {
public:
    stringConnector() = default;
    virtual ~stringConnector() = default;
}
```

stringConnector.cpp

```
template<>
void iConnector::transfer<std::string>(std::string str)
{
    std::cout << "stringConnector " << str << "\n";
}
```

Thank you for suggestions.
Adrian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical form of a variadic template function uses rvalue references and `std::forward`:

```
template<typename... T>
void echo(iConnector& connector, T&&... args)
{
    connector.transfer(std::forward<T>(args)...);
}
```

This will prevent your strings from being copied.

You don't need a template function to overload the variadic form:

```
void iConnector::transfer(int i)
```

The compiler will choose this overload if the parameter is an `int`.

Your `connector::transfer` might be better described as `const`:

```
void iConnector::transfer(int i) const
```

This carries over to your connector reference:

```
void echo(iConnector const &connector, T&&... args)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that this should be posted on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you overload `iConnector::transfer(int i)`, which will be called if you pass `transfer(1L)`?

Comment: It should be the variadic overload because `int` and `long` are distinct types, even if they are the same size. Your compiler may think otherwise.